# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when trying to use subprocess in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to run a program many times in parallel (with different arguments). I searched online and found that subprocess in python is a good way to do that. My code is the following:

```
import subprocess
import os

models_path="~/"
procs = []
num_of_procs_running=0
i = 0
for model_name in os.listdir(models_path):
    if num_of_procs_running > num_of_procs:
        for p in procs:
            p.wait()
        procs = []
        num_of_procs_running = 0
    elif model_name.endswith(".onnx"):
        name, ending = model_name.split(".")
        runner = './SOME_PROGRAM '+str(i)+'> output.txt'
        i+=1
        procs.append(subprocess.Popen(runner,shell=True))
        num_of_procs_running += 1
        print("Total processes:",num_of_procs_running)
        print("\n")
for p in procs:
    p.wait()
```

I am getting Segmentation Fault(core dumped) if I am trying to run more than 56 subprocesses. My machine has 56 CPU's and and each CPU has 12 cores. How can I run more than 56 subprocesses, or maybe use threads?
Thanks.

Comment: Your first step in debugging this needs to be to find a way to reliably trigger the segfault when running your `MY_PROGRAM` executable directly. Then fire up a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) and see why it's crashing. Your Python code is not the problem here -- the problem lies in `MY_PROGRAM` somehow.

Comment: As an aside: don't use `shell=True`, especially when you're assembling the arguments manually like this. Just pass a list of arguments directly.

Comment: Is there a reason you do not use `name` and `ending`?

Comment: @DavidCullen yes. It is being use in my original code. It's not necessary for this post.. It's one of the arguments sent to the program.

Comment: @DanielPryden I read online that if you are passing arguments in one string you should apply shell=True. Isn't that right? Also, when running MY_PROGRAM directly there is no seg fault. What should I do?

Comment: @GuyOhayon: Mostly you should avoid passing arguments in one string. Why launch a whole separate process (the shell) just to parse a string into a list of strings for you? And if you accidentally assemble the string incorrectly, the shell could execute arbitrary commands you didn't expect, whereas if you pass a list of strings, that doesn't happen. But addressing your other comment: can you reproduce *exactly* the same command line in both cases? Can you try otherwise to reproduce the environment (match up env vars, redirect or close stdin/stdout, etc.)?

Comment: Maybe it is just your slimmed down example, but you never add your subprocess `p` to `procs`. Thus, the current program will not wait for your subprocesses to finish. I guess that could lead to odd problems down the road.

Comment: I updated my code. I have 56 CPU's and if I try to run 56 subprocesses everything works fine, but 57 and above gives me segfault. What should I do if I want to run more? Each CPU has 12 cores. Thanks.

Comment: Done. Can you check it now? @asynts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As @danielpryden already [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064036/segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-trying-to-use-subprocess-in-python#comment91080917_52064036) don't invoke a shell:

   ```
   import subprocess

   # bad (mocking your code)
   p = subprocess.Popen("echo 1 > output.txt", shell=True)
   p.wait()

   # better
   fp = open("output.txt", "w")
   p = subprocess.Popen(["echo", "1"], stdout=fp)

   p.wait() # or do something else
   fp.close() # remember to close file
   ```
2. When reaching the maximum number of threads, it waits until *all* threads have finished, quite inefficient. What you seemingly try to achieve is exactly what [`multiprocessing.pool.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool) does:

   ```
   from multiprocessing.pool import Pool

   # mocking your code
   modules = ["mod1.onnx", "mod2.onnx"]

   def run(module):
     print("running", module)

   # use the maximum number of threads by default
   with Pool() as pool:
     pool.map(run, modules)
   ```
3. The segmentation fault isn't caused by your Python application, but rather from whatever program you try to execute. If it's C++ have a look at [`std::thread::hardware_concurrency`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/hardware_concurrency); You need to change the program code not your python script.

Comment: Comments [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194020/discussion-on-answer-by-asynts-segmentation-fault-core-dumped-when-trying-to-u).